# Comparing url model and the real one

Tags: php, url, compare, match, uri

I have this url type:
`/segment1/segment2`

I need to focus on segment2 that contains the id or the code of the item and some other slug or date etc infos.

Example: 
`/segment1/123-title-of-the-item`
or `/segment1/title-of-the-item-123`
or `/segment1/DLCK34Z-other-text`

and so on..

Let's consider the first example:

the model is `/segment1/{id}-{slug}`

In order to get the item from the database, I need to identify from "123-title-of-the-item" the id.

I need to get an array like:

```
['id'] => 123
['slug'] => title-of-the-item
```

In other words, I need to know for any cases which substring of the url corresponds to the patner element.

All the fields between `{` and `}` are fields on the database table and I already know the table name of the item.

Do you have any script, class, function or suggestion?

Comment: In the last example DLCK34Z is the {item_code} instead of the {id} so in that case I need to get ['item_code'] => DLC34Z

Answer (score 0):

Naive implementation:

```
<?php

$url = '/segment1/x-title-of-the-item-123';

// Get the last segment / part
$urlParts = explode('/', $url);
$lastPart = end($urlParts);

// Get ID and slug
$candidates = explode('-', $lastPart);

if ($object = findObjectById(current($candidates))) {
    echo 'ID is at the beginning';
} else if ($object = findObjectById(array_pop($candidates))) {
    echo 'ID is at the end';
} else {
    // No valid ID anywhere
    throw new \Exception('Database record not found');
}

// This is a dummy function, replace it with your own implementation
// that tries to find the database recod by the id. 
// Attention: ID can be a string or a bool (false).
function findObjectById($id)
{
    // Return the database record if it exists or null/false if not
    // Attention: Won't work with the code above if 0 is a valid result!
    return ((int) $id > 0);
}
```

However, I am pretty sure someone else will come up with a better idea.

Update: Okay, if DLCK34Z is not the ID then my attempt won't work for that case. You could ofcourse extend it with a "findObjectByCode" method but things will get messy then.